# Mod Rewrite, Add Language Folder: Mix With Other Rules & Files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site that has different country / locales for the site, but the fundamental file base is the same, just the language file loaded is different.

The site has different urls at the moment including rewrited ones and plain file URL's:

*site.co/index/ - homepage, rewrite URL*

*site.co/members/login.php - plain URL*

Is there a way I can set a rule that'll allow BOTH types to have language / country prefixes (of 2 characters) in front of both as a subfolder?

i.e:

*site.co/au/index/ - homepage, rewrite URL*

*site.co/au/members/login.php - plain URL*

*site.co/de/index/ - homepage, rewrite URL*

*site.co/de/members/login.php - plain URL*

---

My original code was:

```
RewriteRule ^(au|de|cn)/(.*)$ /main/$2?lang=$1 [L,Q]
```

---

An example of the write rule would be fantastic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is actually correct, all you have to do is to remove `Q` from the square brackets at the end.

```
RewriteRule ^(au|de|cn)/(.*)$ /main/$2?lang=$1 [L]
```